# Biztalk Oracle adapter to XML looses zero before the decimal seperator

Tags: oracle, adapter, biztalk

I am using biztalk with an oracle adapter. The query collects data and a few columns have values in them. these values are usually between -1 and 1 and show up in oracle as -0,2 or 0,4

this goes through biztalk and ends up in an xml and looks like the below fields

`<move_cost_vat>-.2</move_cost_vat>`

`<move_cost_customs>0</move_cost_customs>`

`<move_cost_vat>.3</move_cost_vat>`

`<move_cost_customs>.5</move_cost_customs>`

Somehow the leading 0 has disappeared on the decimal numbers. is there a way to prevent this? is this a problem in the adapter?

Comment: Hi Andy, can you advise what version of BizTalk you are running, what version of Oracle database you are talking to and which (BizTalk) Adapter you are using (i.e. the WCF adapter or one of the older ones)?

Comment: @NickHeppleston the server is biztalk server2010, oracle is 10.X and it is using a new WCF adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible work-around is to simply use a map on the port to correctly format the number on the incoming message.

A simple XSL template using the *format-number* function would do the trick (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256225.aspx); as would a standard map using the scripting functoid to invoke a small piece of C#.